# Winusb drive for usb device

Tags: c#, windows, usb, winusb

Anyone tried winusb driver for the usb device in windows 10 to read write usb with c#? I am following micro soft sample applications. But this is for their usk kits and not universal. I have changed the vid and PID. Now able to see my usb devices. However cannot read write the usb endpoint successfully. Is there any one already tried something similar like this?

Comment: It is hard to help you with the actual state of your question, consider editing your question and adding a [mcve] or your problem

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please ask a technical question and don't ask for "any one tried...?" Be more specific. What examples are you referring to and why aren-t they helpful? Show your code and describe where you are stuck. And what is "usk kit"? Are you looking for code tor a Universal Windows Platform (UWP) app? If so, add the appropriate tag.